# What is the "Christian non-denominational" equivalent in Islam?

Tags: non-muslim, christianity, islamic-scholar

Christianity has many thoughts about religion, and they are codified as Catholicism (Catholic) or many Protestant faiths; (Baptist, Methodist, Lutheranism, Reform, Pentecostalism, etc...)

A non denominational is someone who refrains from taking sides in the above complicated mix.  Instead they focus on the things that are universal and apply to all.

I have a friend from Turkey who thinks a Whirling Dervish is similar to a Non Denominational, but it doesn't seem to fit based on my understanding so far.

**Question**

Can anyone describe what's most compatible with a Christian "non-denomiational" in Islam and what does, and does not, carry over between faith perspectives?

Comment: Unlike Christianity, in Islam there is no mix of faiths. All Muslims whether they are from any sect have the same faith. The difference among Muslim sects is in explaining the narrations of Prophet(SAW) and explaining the verses of Quran which all do right. Other difference is in performing worship by different methods which all have been carried out by Prophet. Some stick to one method while others to the other. So I dont think there is any non denominational equivalent in Islam as here is no mix of faiths.

Comment: Or if you could refer us to a page which explains non-denominational in details as I don't know about we may get some knowledge about non-denominationals according to which we will study out and try to find the equivalent. As of your exlanation there is no such thing is Islam.

Comment: There is actually a Wikipedia article on this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondenominational_Muslim

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the "core" beliefs of Islam outside of the 5 pillars?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/24263/what-are-the-core-beliefs-of-islam-outside-of-the-5-pillars)

Comment: See also: "[Why are they called sects in Islam and not denominations?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/14619/9123)"

Answer (score 1):

There's [non-denominational Muslims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-denominational_Muslim), often called "just a Muslim".

Basically, you don't favour a particular sect or school of thought, and just try to worship Allah and follow the teachings of the Prophet Muhammad as best you can.

There's significant practical benefit in avoiding the Sunni-Shia political conflicts.  It also prevents dilemmas where you might agree with a scholar's opinion who doesn't belong to your sect, madhhab, etc.

It may also be justified based on the Qur'an:

> **And hold firmly to the rope of Allah all together and do not become divided.** And remember the favor of Allah upon you - when you were enemies and He brought your hearts together and you became, by His favor, brothers. And you were on the edge of a pit of the Fire, and He saved you from it. Thus does Allah make clear to you His verses that you may be guided.  -- [Qur'an 3:103](https://quran.com/3/103)

There's a [Pew Research Center poll](http://www.pewforum.org/2012/08/09/the-worlds-muslims-unity-and-diversity-1-religious-affiliation/#identity) giving the demographics on this, and being "just a Muslim" is not unusual globally.

Comment: I have literally met people who refuse to even be called a "non-denominational Muslim", since "non-denominational" itself is seen as a denomination. Anything beyond just "Muslim" would be out-and-out unacceptable.